# what is the exception in this code

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    printf("main started");
    for(;;) {}
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is this it does not print "main started". Doesn't matter what is in for loop and how many statements are there before loop.

Comment: The output is buffered.

Comment: Please provide more information. What compiler do you use and what is the platform that you are working on?

Comment: Sure it does matter what is there in the for loop: put `return 0;` in it and see what happens.

Comment: hugh, main() is a technically corrrect way to declare the main entry point, but please use 'int main(){ ... return 0;}.

Comment: @georgesl It's neither technically correct in the current version of C nor in any version of C++. So agreed with your conclusion, use `int main()` :)

Comment: gcc compiler and ubuntu 12.10 c language

Comment: @Scroll-lock, gcc compiles C in C89 mode by default. Which is definitely not the modern version and even not the previous one

Comment: In Windows a \n does NOT cause the buffer to flush.  Use fflush(stdout); for portability to all platforms.  Also, the buffer is flushed when the main program terminates, which it NEVER does in your example.  Is `for(;;) {}` necessary??

Comment: no ... A semicolon would do it @JackCColeman

Comment: @Scroll-lock, what I mean is, is the infinite loop implemented by the for statement necessary?  The program never exits and never returns and thus never has a chance to flush the buffer, which is why issuing a `fflush` immediately after `printf` is one solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a newline at the end of the output. Without it the text goes into the output buffer but doesn't get flushed.

Comment: Or force flush it via `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: A newline doesn't guarantee flushing.

Comment: thnx... it's working with "\n" but i still didnt understand. it would work normally but its not working if a forever loop is AFTER it

Comment: When `main` exits the output gets flushed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the output:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Or, terminate the string by `\n` character as most systems have line buffered standard output.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` prints the string only after flushing it. It auto flushes the data if you add `\n` (newline) symbol in the string (although it *usually* works, there is no guarantee! Don't rely on it). Data is also auto-flushed when the program finishes - after returning from the main function or calling `exit`.

In your case program never finishes because of the for loop without a condition, autoflush is never called as a result

If you want to flush it anyway you can force flush yourself calling `fflush(stdout)`. The same function is called automatically at exit.

See the similar question which I asked earlier about standard guarantees regarding auto-flush. [Is there a guarantee of stdout auto-flush before exit? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15911517/2149111)

Answer (score 1):

What you print with `printf()` is saved in a buffer. This means that it's not immediately sent to your console.  However, this buffer is flushed:

- when you print a new-line (`\n`),
- if you ask for a flush,
- or when the buffer becomes too full, and gets flushed automatically.

So, in your case, to see it immediately, add a `fflush(stdout)`, or a do `printf("main started\n")`.