# Implementation dependent outputs of strings

Tags: c++

In the following code, I'm getting only string `a` as output on my mingw compiler but I get both strings as output on an online compiler. Why am I not getting appropriate output on my system?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string a="Welcome";
    string b="HelloWorld";
    for(int i=0;i<=b.length();i++){
        a.push_back(b[i]);
        
    }
    cout<<a<<endl<<b;

     

    return 0;   
}
```

Output-
WelcomeHelloWorld

Comment: Try `cout.flush();` before returning from main, maybe the last line just wasn't displayed. And with "maybe" I mean "most likely or something else is horribly wrong".

Comment: [Usual recommendation against `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: `i<=b.length()` is wrong. Try `<`.

Comment: It's worh noting that you are copying a zero byte into `a` from `b[b.size()]`. It's well-defined, but maybe your terminal gets confused when outputting it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It's not wrong as in "causes UB"-wrong. It will only append a `\0` to `a`. But it's most likely not intended, yes.

Comment: @Scheff it is defined for the non-const version as well as long as you don't modify that null byte.

Comment: What exactly do you get as output? Is it `WelcomeHelloWord` , but you expected a second line?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in mingw in regards of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911517/is-there-a-guarantee-of-stdout-auto-flush-before-exit-how-does-it-work.
add an `endl`

Comment: @churill It is UB up to C++11, defined afterwards.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 ya.....that's my output. Only this line and I expected a 2nd line

Comment: And what output did you expect? Why would there be two lines?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have written both `a` and `b` in `cout`, hence I should get 2 lines

Comment: sorry missed that

Answer (score 2):

one thing you can do is, you can use cout.flush(). If it does not work you can do **a+b** or you can use ***substr()***

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout.flush();
    string a="Welcome";
    string b="HelloWorld";
    cout<<a+b<<endl<<b;
    // cout<<a+b.substr(0,9);
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think cout.flush() sometimes help when getting unwanted output. So, once you can try this also before printing the result.