# std::cout output is not showing in the terminal while debuging my C++ program in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

There is no output being displayed in the terminal during the debug process, it is only displayed after the program has finished executing.

This is during the debug process:
[image: This is during the debug process]

This is after the debug process:
[image: This is after the debug process]

Why is this happening, and how can I get the output to appear during debugging at my breakpoint?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in _textual form_ (see [ask]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to buffering. See [Is std::cout buffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26975876/11107541) (answer: yes it is buffered). You can manually flush `cout` in two ways:

1. Use [the `std::flush` manipulator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush):

   ```cpp
   std::cout << std::flush;
   ```
2. Use [the `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::flush` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush):

   ```cpp
   std::cout.flush();
   ```

As for why the output appears when your program exits, that's because the C++ specification mandates that all open C streams with unwritten buffered data be flushed at program exit. See [Is there a guarantee of stdout auto-flush before exit? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15911517/11107541).